# Best scenario for a mysql array issue

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So I'm after getting a certain array directly from MySQL but I'm not sure if it's possible.

What I am getting is the combination of two tables where the relationship between them is one to many and this is my query

```
        SELECT
        R.id,L.access,L.log_id
        FROM cms_role R
        INNER JOIN cms_roleassign_logs L
        ON R.id = L.rid
        WHERE R.status = 'A'
        ORDER BY R.id
```

That is resulting in the following:

```
[index] => Array("role_id","log_id","access");
```

So with real data it would look something like this

```
[1] => Array(1,4,3)
[2] => Array(1,5,2)
[3] => Array(1,18,3)
[4] => Array(2,15,2)
[5] => Array(2,17,5)
```

What I am after is that format for an array

```
[Role_id] => Array([index] => Array("log_id","access"));
```

So with the previous data it would be like:

```
[1] => Array([0] => Array(4,3), [1] => Array(5,2), [2] => Array(18,3))
[2] => Array([0] => Array(15,2), [1] => Array(17,5)
```

Is it possible to get that out of a mysql query? If not what is the best way to approach this, do I loop on the array result from the query and copy the results in a new array with a different structure?

Comment: And how do you query the database? PDO? MySQLi? A little bit of your code will help

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky MySQLi.. would it make a difference? Am I able to do certain queries on one kind of database that I can not do on another?

Comment: It won't really make a difference but without seeing how you query your database one cant really make a good suggestion. One can write up a sizeable answer only to find out later that you use another api to connect to database.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky would this help? mysql_query($Query,$this->db_val).
It's mysql not mysqli sorry, typo error out of habit.